# Am I required to use form 2555 even if I earn less than the standard deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, foreign-income

I am trying to file my U.S. taxes as an expat in Sweden to try to claim the stimulus check money. I received around $5000 in student grants (which do not need to be repaid) and $5,000 in loans.

I am unemployed (I am a full-time student) and so my total income is $5000. Since the money I received was paid in a foreign country, I should be eligible to the foreign earned income exclusion. However, I do not know what to put as my employer, since I was unemployed. Can I just leave it blank?

I am also eligible for the basic deduction. Can I just put my grants as line 1 of 1040, and then use the standard deduction? Or do I also need to fill out form 2555?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not required to file 2555. [The instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i2555) for form 2555 explain how to choose to exclude foreign earned income. Implicitly, if you have to choose to claim the exclusion, you can choose not to.